# Phonegap / Cordova: jQuery post to external server doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm trying to post some data to an external ressource within a Phonegap / Cordova 3.3.0 app on iOS 7. When I'm calling the jQuery `$.post` method, it doesn't send any data, it throws an exception in my remote debugger:

```
Failed to load resource: file:///var/mobile/Applications/49A5E640-BD77-46EA-A5E5-CCE19ACF6ED2/tracker.app/www/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
    $.post({
      url: 'http://www.my-server.com/json.php',
      data: JSON.stringify({ "lat": event.coords.latitude, "lng": event.coords.longitude }),
      dataType: 'application/json'
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data){
        console.log("Success: " + data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error: " + data);
      }
    });
```

Is there any cross-domain related stuff going on? Or how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line of code to your json.php file and see what happens:

```
header(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *”);
```